# When we initialize weights of a neural net(BP) to zero, what is the error function in this point?

Tags: neural-network

I would like to know about that
If I initialize weights of a BP neural net to zero,then what type is the error function (saddle point,local maxima,local minima ,..)
and I want to infer it mathematically

Answer (score 0):

If the initial weights are zero, neural networks may get stuck in local minima. You can't give them many different starting values if they're all zero.

I'd suggest having a read about Back Propagation and initial weights [here](http://staff.itee.uq.edu.au/janetw/cmc/chapters/BackProp/index2.html).

Edit: As you already stated in your comment, it is indeed a saddle point. Backpropagation based algorithms will normally stop immediately.

Comment: I know BP completely but I think you didn't understand my question
I asked about the error function in starting when we initialize a neural net weights to zero.
I read some posts said it is in a saddle point!
I know it gets stuck in local minima and must use random small weights.